LTspice voltage source paralleled issue; LM2903B, TLV1701
I am running a LTspice simulation for comparators, however I am getting voltage source errors when I place both ICs in the same LTspice file.
The following schematic yields this error:

Voltage source V1 and voltage source E:U1:_U6:_U1:VSS_NEW are
paralleled making an over-defined circuit matrix. You will need to
correct the circuit or add some series resistance


When I ground all the nodes of the LM2903B, I am still getting an error

Voltage source E:U2:_U6:_U1:VSS_NEW is shorted making an over-defined
circuit matrix... You will need to correct the circuit or add some
series resistance


Is there something wrong with my wiring or the spice models I am using for the ICs?

I ran the PSpice LM2903B model in LTspice without issue. Be sure the schematic symbol matches the .lib model pinout. The symbol and lib files are plain text.

Yes i got the LM2903B to work as well, independently, however as soon as i introduce tlv1701 i get a voltage source error

Hmmmm...hey try this.  For each .lib file, cut and paste the first .ENDS you find to the very end of the file.  Let me know if that anything changes.

This looks like an error in the LM2903B model. Where did you get it from?

got it from TI's website
TLV1701 -> https://www.ti.com/product/TLV1701-Q1#design-tools-simulation
lm2903b -> https://www.ti.com/product/LM2903#design-tools-simulation
I downloaded the PSpice models for both sbom859c TLV1701 and slcj011e LM2903b; opened the .lib file in LTspice and right clicked the .SUBCKT line to create symbol (.SUBCKT LM2903B IN+ IN- Vcc GND OUT   )

the main issue is that both these files work independently, when I use them in the same schematic I get issues

Did you try my suggestion?

It looks like you ignored my suggestion in the comments, either intentionally or unintentionally, but I was curious enough to build out your circuit myself to try it out on my own.

My suspicion was that each .lib file has its own set of .subckt building blocks it uses within each file, which is common with TI SPICE models.  The problem is that they are all in global scope which makes them interfere with each other when both files are imported.  The authors of these files should have nested these other .subckt's by having them within the outermost set of .subckt & .ends that correspond to the actual IC part.  We can easily fix this ourselves by doing the following, which makes all those extra .subckt's local only to each file.  I'll do the TLV1701.lib as an example, but you should do it to both files.


Open the .lib file in a text editor (you can use the one within LTspice itself if you like).  Find the .SUBCKT line for the IC you are trying to model.  For the TLV1701, it would be here where the long arrow is pointing to:

...
* Modeled based off of typical EC table specs
*****************************************************************************
* source TLV1701
.SUBCKT TLV1701 IN+ IN- V+ V- OUT     <=============================
X_U4 CMP N857155 Prop_Delay  
X_U2 IN-BUFF IN+BUFF INRANGE V+_BUFFER V-_BUFFER INPUTRANGE  
X_U5 N21237 INRANGE 0 V+ V+_BUFFER V- V-_BUFFER N855856 OUT Output_Stage  
...


From there, scroll down to the first .ENDS statement you find, which would be here:

...
T_TPD         N856745 0 N856751 0 Z0=50 TD=460n  
X_S1    CMP 0 N857155 N857241 Top_Level_S1 
X_S2    CMP 0 N856751 N857241 Top_Level_S2 
E_E1         N855856 V-_BUFFER N857241 V-_BUFFER 2
.ENDS   <=============================
*$
.SUBCKT Input_Buffer IN+ IN+_BUFF IN- IN-_BUFF  
X_U1         IN+ IN- IN+_BUFF IN-_BUFF SUPPLY_BUFFER1 
.ENDS
...


Cut this line CTRL+X and scroll all the way down to the bottom of the file and paste it CTRL+V at the very end such that it looks like the following...and then save the file:

...
.ENDS
*$
.SUBCKT 4ORGATE 1 2 3 4 5 VDD VSS
E1 6 0 VALUE = { IF( ((V(1)> (V(VDD)+V(VSS))/2 ) | (V(2)> (V(VDD)+V(VSS))/2 ) | (V(3)> (V(VDD)+V(VSS))/2 ) | (V(4)> (V(VDD)+V(VSS))/2 )), V(VDD), V(VSS) ) }
R1 5 6 1
.ENDS
*$
.ENDS   <=============================


After doing this procedure to both .lib files, re-run the circuit simulation and it should work without a problem.

